# How to rename the output of reduce output file to the partition number

Tags: mapreduce

I am having some problem with naming the output file of each reduce task with the partition number. How am I going to name the output file with that partition number?
I have looked to the MultipleTextOutputFormat. It can generate a new file with the name of my choice for each key. But I want to name the output file for each partition with the name of my choice i.e. with the partition number.
Please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to subclass OutputFormat class and override few methods in it to achieve solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try `jobConf.getInt("mapred.task.partition", 0)` in your reducer.